# Using javax.jws.WebParam to have more the one WebParam in different xml sub tag

Tags: java

I need to create a method to receive a XML like this . Starting from java code

```
<web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
    <descricaoSumaria>Test file sincrona </descricaoSumaria>
    <fileFullPath>/opt/apagar/file01</fileFullPath>
        <fileType>0</ fileType >
    <fileFullPath>/opt/apagar/*.sh</fileFullPath>
        <fileType>0</ fileType >
    <fileFullPath>…….dynamic number of FileFullPath
</web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
```

My java code is :

```
@WebMethod (operationName = "listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave") String listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave(        
    @WebParam(name = "descricaoSumaria") String descricao , 
    @WebParam(name = "fileFullPath") String [] fileFullPath 
);
```

The implementation is :

```
@Override
public String listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave(String descricao, String [] fileFullPath) {}
```

with this code I have a working method that accept a xml like this  :

```
<web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
    <descricaoSumaria>Test file sincrona </descricaoSumaria>
    <fileFullPath>/opt/apagar/file01</fileFullPath>
    <fileFullPath>/opt/apagar/*.sh</fileFullPath>
    <fileFullPath>/opt/apagar/*.properties</fileFullPath>
</web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
```

How can I add a xml subtag `<fileType>` in tag `<fileFullPath>/` ?

Comment: Sorry the XML that I won’t is :

Comment: <web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
    <descricaoSumaria>Test file sincrona </descricaoSumaria>
    <fileFullPath>
  <file>/opt/apagar/file01</file>
        <type>1</type>
 </fileFullPath>
    <fileFullPath>
        <file>/opt/apagar/file02</file>
        <type>0</type>
 </fileFullPath> 
    <fileFullPath>…….dynamic number of FileFullPath
</web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>